# django python collation error

Tags: python, mysql, django, unicode, mysql-error-1267

What is the reason for the following error?  when i try to filter with:

```
if MyObject.objects.filter(location = aDictionary['address']):
```

where location is defined as:

```
location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
```

I get the following error when aDictionary['address'] contains a string with a non-alphanumeric character (for example Kīhei):

```
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaul
terrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_sw
edish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alter the database in MySQL like so:

```
ALTER TABLE foo CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

When creating a new database, remember to create with the right collate settings:

```
CREATE DATABASE foo CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

More discussion [here](http://wolfram.kriesing.de/blog/index.php/2007/convert-mysql-db-to-utf8).

Comment: So, you recommend dropping the database, including all of its tables and possibly production data, in order to change collation? How about changing that to ALTER statements instead?

Comment: I _swear_ that when I encountered this problem all of the docs said I needed to DROP and CREATE. So I researched, and you're right. Post edited.

Answer (score 1):

Python is using Unicode strings, and your database is not. Change your database collation to use utf8 and you should be fine.